# Buck converter feedback pin routing

Tags: pcb, buck, pcb-layers, routing

I have a question regarding the connection/ routing of the feedback (FB) pin in the buck converters. Consider the following placement example from the [AP64501](https://www.diodes.com/part/view/AP64501/) DS:

[image]

In case of a 2 layer board this is straightforward- There is a trace on the bottom layer that's possibly short.

My question arises for the 4+ layer PCB, in which there is a power plane underneath that has the `VOUT` potential. In that specific case, should we still use a dedicated trace on the bottom layer to tie the FB pin to VOUT (make sure the VIA is islanded on the power plane so it does not touch the plane VOUT potential), or is it ok to simply connect the FB to VOUT via the power plane? Logic tells me the power plane is the best solution ever, as it gives the least resistance between the 2 points (although the FB connection is normally pretty high impedance). On the other hand, one must consider how differently the trace connection vs the plane connection is influenced by different outside signals that could degrade the VOUT voltage accuracy/ ripples. But then again, for the latter I am unable to give any specific explanation, its just a hunch...

[image]

I would appreciate all feedback on this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right, FB routing is inconsequential.  BST is more important I suppose, but still not a big deal overall.

If you're using inner layers GND and VCC, you can discard the top-side GND pour (it's already inside the board!) and route BST straight-line on top, no problem.  (Obviously, keep the vias for the regulator's thermal pad!)  FB can connect through the plane as you surmise.

VOUT doesn't have any current flow across the local area (whereas GND does!), so BST could be a trace on that layer -- that would be fine as well.  You could then shield over the trace with bottom side GND pour to minimize exposed area of the SW node.

If you like, FB can be tied to a more distant point to get tighter regulation there; if you had relatively long trace length or thin plane width on VOUT, I suppose it could compensate for that voltage drop.

My guess is, for any reasonable regulator of this sort (up to 5A or so?), you'd have other problems (heating..?!) for that much voltage drop to be a real problem.  (Maybe at very low voltages i.e. 0.8-1.8V.)  Most cases, the difference is going to be invisible compared to, say, the tolerance of the regulator's VREF in the first place.  Also, you only get to compensate half the drop: the regulator's "-in" is its ground node, which you can't exactly Kelvin-wire to the load(!).

Comment: Thanks cor the answer. Regarding GND on top/ bottom layers- I always keep it on 4+ layer boards for better heat dissipation and gnd resistance lowering. As for the FB, are you saying in the end that it doesnt matter how its routed?

Comment: FB is a fairly low bandwidth signal (control bandwidth, 100s kHz?); as long as it doesn't pick up extreme amounts of noise, or phase shift (don't put it after a bunch of RCs or LCs in the power distribution network..), and the FB node itself stays small (probably better to keep R1 near the reg), yeah, it'll be hard to screw up.